# Checking for Google Play services with FCM SDK

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play) says

> Apps that rely on the Play Services SDK should always check the device
>   for a compatible Google Play services APK ... in two places: in the
>   main activity's onCreate() method, and in its onResume() method.

Why would I perform this check in both my base activity's `onCreate()` and `onResume()`? `onResume()` is guaranteed to be called after `onCreate()` so it seems redundant unless the documentation is making assumptions about when I need play services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the same docs you mentioned, they also stated the reason:

> The check in `onCreate()` ensures that the app can't be used without a successful check. The check in `onResume()` ensures that if the user returns to the running app through some other means, such as through the back button, the check is still performed.

Comment: I read that too, but I feel like you can prevent people from using the app if you had the same logic in onResume.

Comment: @seato - I think that is the point.  Since the check is for ***Apps that rely on the Play Services SDK***. If the app relies on the Play Services SDK to work, it must prevent it from accessing the app without you're desired Play Services SDK version.